# Different Image convert to the same byte and cannot load the image after these

Tags: java, image

After i convert and saved the byte to my P_img column(Image type) in database,it shows me the same byte data with another picture and i can't figure out the reason now. I think different image should have different byte data, am i right?

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package imagecontroller;
import java.sql.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReadParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
/**
 *
 * @author SYNLAPUSR004
 */
public class ImageController {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

    DB db = new DB();
                Connection conn=db.dbConnect(
```

My database address and it works well

"jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.10.19/SyndesEcom/Product","sa","syndes12345!@#$%");
                    db.insertImage(conn,"C:\Users\SYNLAPUSR004\workspace\Mobile_E-Commerce\res\drawable-hdpi\s3.jpg");
                    db.getImageData(conn);
        }

```
   static class DB
{
        public DB() {}
```

The method that are implement to connect to the database

```
        public Connection dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
           String db_userid, String db_password)
        {
                try
                {
                        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
                        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                          db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

                        System.out.println("connected");
                        return conn;

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                }
        }
```

The image will convert to bytearray in the method below

```
        public void insertImage(Connection conn,String img)
        {
                int len;
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                String query;
                PreparedStatement pstmt;
                String pic_Location= "\\\\192.168.10.32\\SyndesEcomAPI\\P_Image\\s3.jpg";

                try
                {
```

Input the location of the image

```
                        File file = new File(img);
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                        byte [] bFile = new byte [(int) file.length()];
                        len = (int)file.length();

                        try
                        {
```

convert the image to byte

```
                             String value;
                             for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(bFile)) != -1;)
                                 bos.write(bFile,0,readNum);
                             byte[] imgBytes = bos.toByteArray();

                       //     value = new String(imgBytes);
                              //set the name of the product that want to add the image and it's location
```

input the image byte data to database

```
                        query = ("UPDATE product set P_Img='"+ imgBytes + "', P_ImgLoc ='"+ pic_Location + "' where P_Name ='"+ "Samsung Galaxy S III 16GB" + "';");
                        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                       // System.out.println(value);
                     //   pstmt.setString(1,file.getName());
                      //  pstmt.setInt(2, len);

                        // Method used to insert a stream of bytes
//                        pstmt.setBinaryStream(3, fis, len); 
                        pstmt.executeUpdate();

                        /*
```

if using the source code start from below part can convert it nicely but if retrieve the byte data from database then it will not show the picture

```
         * 2. How to convert byte array back to an image file?

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgBytes);
        Iterator<?> readers = ImageIO.getImageReadersByFormatName("jpg");

        //ImageIO is a class containing static methods for locating ImageReaders
        //and ImageWriters, and performing simple encoding and decoding. 

        ImageReader reader = (ImageReader) readers.next();
        Object source = bis; 
        ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source); 
        reader.setInput(iis, true);
        ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

        Image image = reader.read(0, param);
        //got an image file

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        //bufferedImage is the RenderedImage to be written

        Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g2.drawImage(image, null, null);

        File imageFile = new File("C:\\Users\\SYNLAPUSR004\\Desktop\\pic\\s4zoom.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", imageFile);


                            //fis.read(bFile);
                            //fis.close();
                */        }
                        catch(Exception ee)
                        {
                            ee.printStackTrace();
                        }


                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
```

The method used to retrieve image data and output to my desktop folder

```
        public void getImageData(Connection conn)
        {

                 byte[] fileBytes;
                 String query;
                 try
                 {
                         query = "select P_Img from product where P_Name ='Samsung Galaxy S4 Zoom'";
                         Statement state = conn.createStatement();
                         ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);
                         if (rs.next())
                        {
                                  fileBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
                                  OutputStream targetFile=  
                                  new FileOutputStream(
                                       "C:\\Users\\SYNLAPUSR004\\Desktop\\pic\\s4zoom2.jpg");

                                  targetFile.write(fileBytes);
                                  targetFile.close();
                        }        

                 }
                 catch (Exception e)
                 {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                 }
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"UPDATE product set P_Img='"+ imgBytes +
```

this just call imgBytes.toString() will get [B@xxxxxx which is not the content of your data.

try this:

```
query = "UPDATE product set P_Img=?...
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setBytes(1, imgBytes);
```